# Native XML Web Services for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, wcf-data-services

I want to share a few small tables from my SQL Server 2008 database. Client is html/javascript based. I started with Native XML Web Services for SQL Server, but it's [deprecated in SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280436.aspx).

Is there any other quick and cheap solution, rather then building data service from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about built in functionality of SqlServer, but you could do it very quickly using [OData](http://www.odata.org/) interface, as described [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx) (there it explains how to build it from scratch using stackoverflow database).

It's using Entity Framework, and it's actually very nice to have, quick to build, doesn't require much knowledge about it, and it's easy to tweak further.

Answer (score 2):

WCF Data Services (REST-based HTTP services) are the way to go and basically replace the "native" SQL Server XML web services.

Read all about [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) and see lots of white papers, tutorials, intro videos and more. The WCF Data Services are Microsoft's concrete implementation of the OData protocol.